# decorator for recursive functions

Tags: python, recursion, python-decorators

i would like to implement decorator  for recursive function, namely fibonnaciy numbers, idea is that as you know  recursive function for large input takes too much time,for this example i have tried  fibonacci numbers, but it returns  following error :
 `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'`

if i run code without decorator, it works fine and returns  corresponding  output, but  with decorator it raises error, i would post code as well

```
           import time
            # start =time.time()
            def time_calculator(func):
                def n_th_number(n):
                    start = time.time()
            
                    print(func(n))
                    end = time.time()
                    print(f'fibonacci lasts for {end - start} second')
                return n_th_number
            @time_calculator
            def fibonacci(n):
                if n==0 or n==1:
                    return n
                else:
            
                   return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
            fibonacci(30)
```

please help me to understand  what is wrong with my code?

full error :

```
1
fibonacci lasts for 0.0 second
0
fibonacci lasts for 0.0 second
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 16, in <module>
    fibonacci(30)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 7, in n_th_number
    print(func(n))
          ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 15, in fibonacci
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 7, in n_th_number
    print(func(n))
          ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 15, in fibonacci
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 7, in n_th_number
    print(func(n))
          ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 15, in fibonacci
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 7, in n_th_number
    print(func(n))
          ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 15, in fibonacci
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 7, in n_th_number
    print(func(n))
          ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 15, in fibonacci
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 7, in n_th_number
    print(func(n))
          ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 15, in fibonacci
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 7, in n_th_number
    print(func(n))
          ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 15, in fibonacci
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 7, in n_th_number
    print(func(n))
          ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 15, in fibonacci
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 7, in n_th_number
    print(func(n))
          ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 15, in fibonacci
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 7, in n_th_number
    print(func(n))
          ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 15, in fibonacci
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 7, in n_th_number
    print(func(n))
          ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 15, in fibonacci
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 7, in n_th_number
    print(func(n))
          ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 15, in fibonacci
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 7, in n_th_number
    print(func(n))
          ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 15, in fibonacci
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 7, in n_th_number
    print(func(n))
          ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 15, in fibonacci
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 7, in n_th_number
    print(func(n))
          ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 15, in fibonacci
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 7, in n_th_number
    print(func(n))
          ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 15, in fibonacci
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 7, in n_th_number
    print(func(n))
          ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 15, in fibonacci
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 7, in n_th_number
    print(func(n))
          ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 15, in fibonacci
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 7, in n_th_number
    print(func(n))
          ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 15, in fibonacci
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 7, in n_th_number
    print(func(n))
          ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 15, in fibonacci
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 7, in n_th_number
    print(func(n))
          ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 15, in fibonacci
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 7, in n_th_number
    print(func(n))
          ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 15, in fibonacci
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 7, in n_th_number
    print(func(n))
          ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 15, in fibonacci
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 7, in n_th_number
    print(func(n))
          ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 15, in fibonacci
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 7, in n_th_number
    print(func(n))
          ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 15, in fibonacci
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 7, in n_th_number
    print(func(n))
          ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 15, in fibonacci
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 7, in n_th_number
    print(func(n))
          ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 15, in fibonacci
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 7, in n_th_number
    print(func(n))
          ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 15, in fibonacci
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 7, in n_th_number
    print(func(n))
          ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\New_AI_Era\time_estimation.py", line 15, in fibonacci
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: Your `n_th_number` function should *return* the value you got from calling `func`.

Comment: `def n_th_number` **always returns `None`**

Comment: Your inner function `def n_th_number(n)` only prints, it doesn't return anything; it hs no return statement, so implicitly it returns `None`. That's what your traceback is telling you. Don't confuse a print statement with return statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrapper still needs to call the function and return the value that it would have returned.

```
           import time
            # start =time.time()
            def time_calculator(func):
                def n_th_number(n):
                    start = time.time()
                    result = func(n)
                    print(result)
                    end = time.time()
                    print(f'fibonacci lasts for {end - start} second')
                    return result
                return n_th_number
```

Comment: can i move print statment to the left? i mean text  part

Comment: The important thing in this case is that the wrapper must return whatever value the original function returns.  The critical lines above are `result = func(n)` and `return result`.  Everything else is up to you.